# How does Heroku dyno sleeping & waking work under the covers?

Tags: heroku, amazon-ec2, architecture, devops

This is something I've wondered for awhile - specifically, how to turn on a container or server upon receiving a connection request (getting it to sleep after x minutes of inactivity is pretty easy).

Let's say I had an EC2 instance on AWS that was turned off. Upon navigating to its DNS URL or IP address, I would want the server to wake up and serve up its content to the client. Heroku is currently managing to do this, and I've always wondered what was going on behind the scenes...and I know cloud servers like AWS don't usually have wake-on-lan functionality.

I had some ideas about what may be happening - perhaps sleeping dynos aren't actually 'turned off', but are just forcefully idled. It also may be possible that they are containers attached to a larger 'mother' server that is receiving the connection request, spooling up sleeping servers, and then forwarding the connection to the activated server. Anyone with architectural knowledge know what the secret sauce is?

As you can probably tell, I know practically nothing about dev ops or managing servers. This is just something that's been scratching my curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hypothesis!
Imagine a `Kubernetes` environment with the horizontal pod `autoscaler (HPA)` configured to keep `0` pods active.
This would make Node still have the reserved resources, however, unused, allowing it to be allocated to other clients and/or applications.
When you perform a `wake-up`, you are actually configuring the `HPA` to keep active pods above `0`, giving the impression of shutting down and restarting your application.

Comment: How does Kubernetes relate to Amazon Web Services?

Comment: I currently believe that great services that have availability, scalability and reability are based on Kubernetes, in the case of AWS, on the EKS service. As shown in some AWS re: Invent, Heroku uses these services to be elastic.

Answer (score -2):

AWS EC2 has an [API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) with which you can control/provision servers as you do via their dashboard.

Comment: It would take much longer to spin up an EC2 instance. Heroku dynos start in seconds, sometimes 2, 3 seconds.